# Cambiar los colores por defecto de una gráfica 'pie' Highcharts según datos de una BD

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, highcharts, charts

Estoy tratando de cambiar los colores que por defecto otorga highcharts en una gráfica circular, estoy utilizando codeigniter, php y mysql. Los datos a mostrar los estoy extrayendo de una consulta a una tabla de la base de datos de mysql con un `foreach`, por lo que el número de datos varía de acuerdo a las columnas de la tabla consultada. ¿Como puedo asignar colores personalizados de acuerdo a cada grupo de datos? dejo una imagen de resultado hasta el momento y el código del script.

[image: Resultado hasta el momento]

Código del problema:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 45,
        beta: 0
    }
},
title: {
    text: '<h6>Distribución de Acervos respecto al total de objetos digitales<h6>'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y} (<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>)'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        depth: 35,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f}%'
        },
        showInLegend: true 
    }
},
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Porcentaje',
    data: [

        <?php foreach ($totalPorAcervo as $key): ?>
            ['<?=$key->Acervo ?>', <?=$key->Total ?>             
            ],
        <?php endforeach ?>

       ]
      }]
     });
   </script>
```

Hasta el momento no he probado otras alternativas.